# C++ code performance strings compare

Tags: c++, string, performance

I have an array of struct (arrBoards) which has some integer values, vector and a string type.
I want to compare if certain string in the struct is equal with entered parameter (string p1).

What idea is faster - to check equation of input string with every string element inside an array, or firstly check if string.length() in current string element of the array greater than 0, then compare the strings.

```
if (p1.length())
{
    transform(p1.begin(), p1.end(), p1.begin(), ::tolower); //to lowercase
    for (int i=0; i<arrSize; i++) //check if string element already exists
        if ( rdPtr->arrBoards[i].sName == p1 )
        {
            */ some code */
            break;
        }
}

if (p1.length())
{
    transform(p1.begin(), p1.end(), p1.begin(), ::tolower); //to lowercase
    for (int i=0; i<arrSize; i++) //check if string element already exists
        if ( rdPtr->arrBoards[i].sName.length() ) //check length of the string in the element of the array
            if ( rdPtr->arrBoards[i].sName == p1 )
            {
                */ some code */
                break;
            }
}
```

I think the second idea is better because it don't need to calculate the name everytime, but I can be wrong because using if could slow down code.

Thanks for the answers

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `sName == p1` will do a length check first (actually `!empty()`) so you may be doubling the number of length checks.. I would profile it but my guess is don't bother with the length check

Comment: If performance is a concern, you might better look at different approaches, like hash-tables, sorting the array according to the string, ...

Comment: Galik's comment is essentially what it comes down to. Whether or not _your_ compiler/STL implementation does this may depend on your particular platform/compiler etc (although I would expect any modern implementation to take the `!empty()` shortcut). So you are probably best off doing some benchmarking on your own.

Comment: The comments of Galik and mindriot are both valid - but whatever the outcome of such a benchmark is, it may still not be a good idea to let this become a driver of your design decision: Your environment may change (different machine / operating system / compiler / compiler version / library version), making all previous benchmarks useless.  And, design alternatives on a higher level are likely to have a much higher impact on overall performance.

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure the comparison operator (==) of the string class is already optimized enough. Just use it.

operator==(...) returns a bool based on a short-circuit comparison

```
return __x.size() == __n && _Traits::compare(__x.data(), __s, __n) == 0;
```

It checks the size of the strings before calling compare(), so, there is no need for further optimization.

Always remember one of the principles of Software Engineering: KISS :P

Comment: I am afraid you are wrong here. The equal operator in std::string (at least in MS VS2013) is implemented as `return (_Left.compare(_Right) == 0);`.  It means it first calculates which string is "greater" in lexicographical order by doing `memcmp()` on the common length part. For example, comparing a string of 1,000,000 A's to a string of 1,000,001 A's will take some time.

Comment: @VladFeinstein, could you tell me where you got that from

Comment: the function string::compare() and string::==() are different. string::==() calls compare() behind scenes. As you said compare() is at a memory level.

Comment: That's what I said above: `is implemented as...`. My argument is against your statement `comparison operator (==) of the string class is already optimized enough`; it obviously is not. If you are only interested in equal/not equal, and don't care which string is greater - I can do better.

Comment: https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/string see the implementation of operator==, you will see it uses a short-circuit comparison => __x.size() == __n && _Traits::compare(__x.data(), __s, __n) == 0;

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is play percentages.
Since the strings are highly likely to be different, you want to find that out as quickly as possible.

You're comparing length first, but don't assume length is cheap to compute, compared to whatever else you're doing.

Here's the kind of thing I've done (in C):

```
if (a[0]==b[0] && strcmp(a, b)==0)
```

so if the leading characters are different, it never gets to the string compare.
If the dataset is such that the leading characters *are* likely to be different, it saves a lot of time.
(`strcmp` also has this kind of optimization, but you still have to pay the price of setting up the arguments and getting in and out of the function. We're talking about small numbers of cycles here.)

If you do something like that, then you may find the loop iteration overhead is costing a significant fraction of time.
If so, you might consider unrolling it.
(The compiler might unroll it for you, but I wouldn't depend on it.)

Comment: Apart from the fact, it's C and using c str, with strcmp, thanks. I get it. The first are main characters compared and when its passed, it jumps to the next routine where the whole string is compared.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing a number is faster than comparing a string. Try comparing the strings length before comparing the string itself.

Comment: @EdHeal `string::length` is required to take constant time.